# count page pdf that contain image

Tags: php, pdf, count

i have a pdf file containing the image.
i've tried use [Imagick::identifyImage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-identifyimage.php), use manual preg_match, still cannot count how much page pdf file that containing images
or
can count images in a pdf ? let say in 1 page of pdf is an image
Anyone can help ?

Thanks before

Comment: do you want to count number of images in a pdf file?

Comment: yes, if there are the way to count images in a pdf

Answer (score 0):

Use Imagick

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getnumberimages.php

```
<?php

$document = new Imagick('{yourpdffilename}.pdf');

var_dump($document->getNumberImages()); //returns 2

$document = new Imagick('{yourpdffilename}.pdf');

var_dump($document->getNumberImages()); //returns 1

?>
```

Comment: Isn't this the page count?

Comment: The function name says it all get - Number - Images.

Comment: ...in the object. And the object itself is an Imagick instance. It represents an image or a set of images. When using with PDF files without a page suffix (e.g. [1]) it is an image set. Each image repesents a page.